# html5 post form to server, how to open a link from server on client side?

Tags: php, html, rest, client-server, restful-url

I have a website with client side(jqm, html5) and server side(rest api in php).

So my question is like this:

I have a simple post form

```
<form  name="loginform" method="post" action="http://serveraddress/sn/logout"> 
           <input type='text' name="user" placeholder="Username" style="text-align: center" required/>  
           <input type="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password" style="text-align: center" required/>   
          <input  type="submit" value="Sign In" data-icon='check'/>
          </form
```

>

logout is a function on server.

```
 /**
     * Logs in a user with the given username and password POSTed. 
     *
     * @url POST /sr/logout
     */
    public function logout()
    {
   header("Location: http:...logout.html"); //whatever address
     }
```

logout function displays logout page. but doesn't show it in the address bar.
It shows http:...logout instead of http:...logout.html!!

Why does it do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can do the post via jquery, and from the server return a json response with the url to be redirect(like logout.html).

Comment: ye, was thinking about it as an option if redirect from server won't  work. Trying to open url from server though with a post form, not ajax.

Comment: Is it possible that you are not including a redirect status code (3xx)?

Comment: i'm just doing redirect like in my post. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: It all works, I need the url to display in address bar!